How can I see the record selection criteria behind a Table object in SQL Server Management Studio?
I'm trying to find the SQL record selection criteria (WHERE clause) that is used by a table object in SQL Server Management Studio (Object Explorer > Database > 'Tables' folder).
I have a stored procedure which is pulling from a table object, so I want to check that table to see what criteria it's using.
I've tried: right click table > Script Table As > Create To > New Query Editor Window). However, this just shows me a SELECT list of the columns used in the table object, it does not include the criteria used to pull the records (WHERE clause).
Is there something I'm missing here?  If I use that same method on a stored procedure object, it opens the full SQL query and I can see the tables and criteria used. How can I do the same for a table object?
Tables
Thanks!

The screen shot you sent is of a list of tables, there is no where clause in the table creation scripts.  This is just the table definition. If you are thinking of a saved query on the table those would be views or Stored Procedures

It's a filtered list @Brad .

Thanks for the reply.  I think I see now.  I found a different stored procedure which is inserting records into the Table that I was curious about, so I think I have my answer there now.  However, out of curiosity, if I have a table object like that, is there any easy way to find which stored procedure is being used to load the records into it?  I got kind of lucky by finding it this time, wasn't sure if there was a way to lookup the stored procedure which is loading the records for a table.

Aside... mainstream support for SQL Server 2008 R2 ended back in 2014. Is your upgrade plan blocked by something?

@mt1: In the SQL Server Management Studio, there is no straightforward way to find cross-references, i.e. where a table is referenced by other DB objects like views, stored procedures, functions or triggers. Or at least I do not know of any.
One way could be to generate a script for the whole DB by right-clicking the DB name -> Tasks -> Generate scripts.
I am using JetBrains DataGrip IDE for working with DBs which has this cross-reference search feature built in. However, it's not free but JetBrains products saved me many times tbh so they were worth the investment.

That was just an example screenshot from google to show the Tables section I was referring to

Install the RedGate SQL Search add-in for SSMS. This will find references to tables (actually it looks for text matches but that will be OK).

In SSMS if you right click the table and choose the 'View Dependencies' it does show you a list of all the objects that use that table.

Tables don't have a where clause. That doesn't make any sense. If you script a table you get the t-sql that would be used to create the table. Tables don't have some criteria, they are just a container to hold data rows.
